# c# json json.net parse to class

Tags: c#, json

For some time I have a problem with the code.
Trying to retrieve data from the API using the json but when trying to parse json and send it to the class I receives empty string.

The json data looks like this

```
{"Wynik":{"Token":"String","DataCzasWaznosci":"\/Date(-62135596800000-0000)\/"}
```

... and this is my code:

```
public void post()
{
    Autoryzacja_zaloguj a_zaloguj = new Autoryzacja_zaloguj();
    string url = a_zaloguj.Link;
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);


    byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a_zaloguj.Json);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/json";
    req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
    Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);

    string backstr = sr.ReadToEnd();
    dynamic d = JObject.Parse(backstr);
    var wynik = d.Wynik;
    string token = wynik.Token;
    DateTime data = wynik.DataCzasWaznosci;

    Wyniki wyniki = new Wyniki();
    wyniki.test = token;

    sr.Close();
    res.Close();
}

public class Wyniki
{
    public string test { get; internal set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please include a sample of the json you are receiving?

Comment: Of course: {"Wynik":{"Token":"String","DataCzasWaznosci":"\/Date(-62135596800000-0000)\/"}

Answer (score 0):

You could use Newtosoft nugget package for this kind of parsing
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

```
public class Wynik
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCzasWaznosci { get; set; }
}

/*Deserialization part */
string backstr = sr.ReadToEnd();
Wynikm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wynik>(backstr);
```

Comment: its not working. Still geting empty result in Messagebox.

Comment: No only empty Messagebox, Here is my code after chenges: http://pastebin.com/uU2wHFuv

Comment: http://pastebin.com/C7Yf9ETj this is button code. In API log there is info that API token is generating so i think there is problem passing data to class.

Comment: you messabox is empty because you use a empty object Autoryzacja_zaloguj.Wynik wynik = new Autoryzacja_zaloguj.Wynik(); you should  return a winik object from your post method. Look this http://pastebin.com/dfhuA8Ay

Comment: I was trying earlier this but now i have error Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable on var wynik = a_zaloguj.post();

Comment: public void post() should be public Wynik post()

Comment: Ok but i need result from method in class because its gonna be using in whole project not only in MessageBox.

Comment: So you should retrieve a string from your post method & parse the string out of this method

Comment: Ok but i srill have to pass string From method... So we are back to previous problem.

Comment: so you can't use this method is your whole project... i think you did not think about the architecture of your application which led to your problem. You should work in the architecture of your project before starting implement something.

Comment: I will have 40-50 json strings so i wan tto have, json serialized and deserialized class, http link, parse method in one place... Because then i can simply use them in form.

Comment: I was able to improve the code. When I use the debugger class Wyniki has data. Unfortunately they do not show in MesageBox.